# Ember.Select with an unbound options list

Tags: javascript, data-binding, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

In an ember.js application that I am working on (ember v1.8.0-beta1, ember-cli), I have a page with a simple sign-up type form that includes a country select dropdown. The problem is that since this field has a relatively large number of options (244 to be exact), there is a big rendering performance hit, the route takes almost a full second longer to render when that select field is added to the template.

I assummed that this slowdown was due to Ember having to create bindings for each of the 244 `<option>` views within the select, so following [this cookbook entry](https://github.com/emberjs/website/pull/1402/files?short_path=5a71fab) that I found, I attempted to create an unbound version of `Ember.Select` like so:

app/views/unbound-select.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Select.extend({
    optionView: Ember.SelectOption.extend({
        templateName: 'unbound-option'
    })
});
```

app/templates/unbound-option.hbs

```
{{unbound view.label}}
```

app/templates/signup.hbs

```
...
{{view "unbound-select" value=country content=countries}}
...
```

However, doing this instead of using a regular `Ember.Select` does not seem to help with the rendering speed at all. Is there maybe something that I'm missing in my implementation that would be causing all the `<option>`'s to still be bound?

Comment: Any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as your unbound extension of `Ember.Select` is just as slow, I'd venture that `Ember.Select` is simply slow.  From [the docs](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/views/built-in-views/), last paragraph:

> The select view is extremely feature-rich, and may perform badly when rendering many items. Due to this, it has not yet been converted into an component or helper like other inputs.